# Connecting to MariaDb on Windows through putty ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, mariadb, putty

Background: I've been connecting to MySql from Windows to an Ubuntu VM through putty's ssh tunnel for years now, and it's worked great.

2 weeks ago I started up a new Ubuntu 16.06 amd64 VM, put the latest MariaDb on it, and everything worked as before. Workbench worked, and my code was able to connect through the tunnel as well.

Last week, the connection somehow became unstable. It would not connect anymore, and timeouts would occur 100% of the time until it mysteriously started working again. Even now, at the beginning of writing this question, it was not working. Now it is. It has sometimes not worked when ufw was disabled completely. Does anyone know what is going on? Are there timeouts or cooldowns on the various pieces that I'm not aware of? I've restarted the service countless times, and the VM many times as well.

Configuration:

```
my.cnf:
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

ufw:
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306 on lo                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
127.0.0.1 3306/tcp         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6) on lo            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: I don't have it 100% solved, but it appears to be an interaction between putty on the Windows side, and MariaDb. Possibly need to fully restart putty after changes on the Linux side.

Comment: MySql Workbench connects 100% of the time. My app does not. It appears to be some kind of Windows / putty interaction bug.